# What is the meaning of 'wet bone' here?

Tags: word-meaning

> Later, some knew it as a place that bred malefic spirits. Spring
>   starvation showed skully heads, knobbed joints beneath flesh. What
>   desperate work to stay alive, to scrob and claw through hard times.
>   The alchemist sea changed fishermen into **wet bones**, sent boats to
>   drift among the cod, cast them on the landwash.

*The Shipping News by Annie Proulx*

What is the meaning of '**wet bones**' here? It sounds like 'coward'. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know the book, but maybe it means bones of the lost fishermen in the ocean?

Comment: @user3169 never thought of that! makes perfect sense! Thank you!

Comment: skully heads ... knobbed joints beneath flesh ... wet bones...

Comment: @Tromano   Why couldn't I see that? Hmm... I wonder it's my lack of imagination or English.  ;)  Thank you.

Comment: I think maybe you were using too much imagination. The meaning is literal in this case.

Comment: I think it must have been "alchemist", which mixes the metaphor.

Comment: The work was so hard, and the compensation so little, that the workers lost weight ("starvation showed skully heads, knobbed joints beneath flesh"); the work was at sea, so they were wet ("wet bones"). She personifies the work as "the sea", and the transformation as a kind of magic (thus the sea is an "alchemist"). The fishermen are not necessarily reduced to literal bone (although it does evoke an image of death), but the effect is so shocking that it appears supernatural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means

> **the bones of the lost fishermen in the ocean**